# A "fast" way for computing $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{100} n\times 2^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

> How to compute 'z', where $\displaystyle z = \sum_{n=1}^{100} n\times 2^n$ ?

The answer is of the form $99 \times 2^{101} + 2$, I need a fast approach as this problem is supposed to be solved under a minute.

Comment: Hint: start from the binomial theorem and differentiate accordingly...

Comment: @Aryabhata:Thanks for that pointing out to that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can actually solve this problem without calculus.  (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series/30741#30741).)

**Full Solution:**  Lets find a general formula for the following sum for any $r,m$: $$S_{m}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}.$$

This can be derived in a similar manner to the formula for the geometric series. Notice that $$S_{m}-rS_{m}=-mr^{m+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{m}r^{n}$$

$$=-mr^{m+1}+\frac{r-r^{m+1}}{1-r}=\frac{mr^{m+2}-(m+1)r^{m+1}+r}{1-r}.$$  Hence $$S_m = \frac{mr^{m+2}-(m+1)r^{m+1}+r}{(1-r)^2}.$$
This equality holds for any $r$, so by letting $r=2$ we are able to conclude

$$\sum_{n=1}^m n2^n = m2^{m+2}-(m+1)2^{m+1}+2=2^{m+1}(m-1)+2.$$

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 11):

If you define $y=\sum_{n=1}^{100}x^n=\frac{x^{101}-1}{x-1}$, then $z=x\frac{dy}{dx}$ evaluated at $x=2$.  I love taking the derivative with respect to $2$.

Comment: +1 for "derivative with respect to 2" (and clever answer). :)

Comment: Yes, lotta fun differentiating with respect to constants, but best to do it before they completely settle down. :)

Comment: Failing to differentiate between variables and constants invariably and constantly leads to trouble.