# Proving $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n  i 2^{i-1} = (n+1) 2^n - 1$ by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, summation

I'm trying to apply an induction proof to show that $((n+1) 2^n - 1 $ is the sum of $(i 2^{i-1})$ from $0$ to $n$.

- the base case: L.H.S = R.H.S
- we assume that $(k+1) 2^k - 1 $ is true.
- we need to prove that $(k+2) 2^{k+1} - 1$

My try to prove 3 is as follows:

$(k+2) 2^{k+1} - 1$

$(k+2) (2^k * 2) - 1$ , from 2: $2^k = 1/(k+1)$

$(k+2) (2 / (k+1)) - 1$

$(k+1) 2 - 1$

My question is, how could I get to $2^k$ from the last line to prove this formula is right?

Comment: I don't think you have the right formula. It does not hold for $n=1$.

Comment: Two similar questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53496/a-fast-way-for-computing-sum-limits-n-1100-n-times-2n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-r-1d-r-cdot-2r (But I do not think that this should be closed as duplicate - since OP is asking about mistake in his approach and he is interested only in the proof by induction. I just wanted to point him to similar question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your statement. You want to show $$  \sum_{i=0}^n i 2^{i-1} = n 2^n - 2^n + 1 $$

Base case $n = 0$:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^0 i 2^{i-1} = 0 = 0 - 1 + 1$$

Assume that $$ \sum_{i=0}^n i 2^{i-1} = n 2^n - 2^n + 1$$

Then make an induction step from $n$ to $n+1$. This means you want to show that given your assumption you can show

$$  \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i 2^{i-1} = (n+1) 2^{n+1} - 2^{n+1} + 1$$

Do this as follows:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i 2^{i-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} i 2^{i-1} + (n+1)2^n = n 2^n - 2^n + 1 + (n+1)2^n  = n 2^{n+1} + 1 = (n+1)2^{n+1} - 2^{n+1} + 1$$

Which is what you wanted to show. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this right? $(n+1)2^n+(n+1 )2^n-1 = 2(n+1)2^n-1=(n+1)2^{n+1}-1$... The OP's formula does not hold for $n=1$.

Comment: Darn, you're right!

Comment: @DavidMitra: Let's assume it's a typo. Let's see whether I can fix this.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thanks, David. Fixed.

Comment: @Sosy: Thank you, my pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\ $ The RHS should be $\rm\:(n-1)\ 2^n + 1\:.\:$ As *always*, by [telescopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy), the inductive step arises from equating the first difference of the LHS and RHS. Here that yields the trivially proved identity

$$\rm (n+1)\ 2^n\ =\ n\ 2^{n+1} - (n-1)\ 2^n $$

which, combined with the trivial proof of the base case $\rm\:n=0\:,\:$ completes the proof by induction.

**REMARK** $\ $ Note that absolutely no ingenuity is required. The proof by telescopy is so mechanical that it can be done by a machine. Indeed, cancelling the factor of $\rm\:2^n\:,\:$ said inductive step reduces to proving the polynomial identity $\rm\ n+1\ =\ 2\:n - (n-1)\:.\:$ For much further discussion see my many [posts on telescopy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy)

Comment: sounds very helpful, but hmmm what is the first difference of the LHS and RHS? at what value (k or k+1)?

Comment: @Sosy The first difference of $\rm\:f(n)\:$ wrt $\rm\:n\:$ is $\rm\:\Delta_n f(n) := f(n+1) - f(n)\:.\:$ The displayed equation above is $\rm\: \Delta\: LHS(n) = \Delta\: RHS(n)\:.\:$ This method works to mechanically "discover" the induction step on all problems of this type. See the linked posts on telescopy for background.