# How to find 50-th term of this sequence and its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can someone help me with this excercise?

I recognize that the numerator is simply increasing by factors of 2, and every time a new number is written it begins from 1 again. I know that the denominator is similar in the sense that you write a natural number to the second power n times (where n=that natural number). I also know how to get the denominator of a50 (it is 100) and how to get the numerator (it is 9). I need help with (2) and (3). The problem is done without calculator.

> Let $a_n$ be the $n$th term of the following sequence:
>   $$\frac11,\frac14,\frac34,\frac19,\frac39,\frac59,\frac1{16},\frac3{16},\frac5{16},\frac7{16}\dots$$
>
> 1. Find $a_{50}$.
> 2. Find $\sum_{n=1}^{50}a_n$.
> 3. Find the maximal $n$ satisfying $a_n\ge\frac1{10}$.

Answers:

1. 0.09
2. 9.25
3. 190

Comment: My guess is I should look at the sequence as two different ones. Then I know that to find the sum I should identify how many times does each number appear and multyply. Then I should do a summation. Opinions?

Comment: So like 1 appears ten times in the numerator, 2 nine times, 3 eight times.... So the sum would be 1(10)+2(9)+3(8)...

Comment: For the denominator each number appears sqrt(n) times (where n is a natural number). Thus the summation would be 1^3+2^3+3^3,...5(10^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest and most straightforward way to solve this problem is to use a double sum.  It's obvious that the denominators are squares, and the numerators are odd numbers.  So we simply write the inner sum as $$\sum_{k=1}^m (2k-1),$$ and the outer sum is $$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m^2}.$$  So the total sum is $$\sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{2k-1}{m^2}.$$  Then the $50^{\rm th}$ term corresponds to some choice of $m$ and $k$.  How do we find it?  Well, we know that the inner sum always has $m$ terms, so we want to choose the smallest $m$ such that $1 + 2 + \cdots + m > 50$, or equivalently, $m(m+1) > 100$.  Clearly $m = 9$ is too small, but $m = 10$ works.  So when $m = 9$ we have summed $9(10)/2 = 45$ terms, and for the next group with $m = 10$, we need $k = 5$ more to get to the $50^{\rm th}$ term.  This means $$a_{50} = \frac{2(5)-1}{10^2} = \frac{9}{100}.$$

With the above in mind we can also compute $$\sum_{n=1}^{50} a_n = \sum_{m=1}^9 \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{2k-1}{m^2} + \sum_{k=1}^5 \frac{2k-1}{10^2}.$$  The first sum is simply $$\sum_{m=1}^9 \frac{1}{m^2} \sum_{k=1}^m (2k-1) = \sum_{m=1}^9 \frac{1}{m^2} \left( 2 \cdot \frac{m(m+1)}{2} - m \right) = \sum_{m=1}^9 1 = 9.$$  The second sum is $$\frac{1}{100} \sum_{k=1}^5 (2k-1) = \frac{1}{100} \left( 2 \frac{5(5+1)}{2} - 5 \right) = \frac{25}{100} = \frac{1}{4}.$$  Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^{50} a_n = \frac{37}{4}.$$

Finally, the largest $n$ such that $a_n \ge \frac{1}{10}$ is easily attained by noting that $2k-1$ is maximized when $k = m$, so all terms in the inner sum are smaller than $\frac{2m - 1}{m^2}$.  So all terms will be less than $1/10$ when $$\frac{2m-1}{m^2} < \frac{1}{10}$$ or $$m > 10 + 3 \sqrt{10}$$ which implies $m  \ge 20$.  Consequently, when $m = 19$, the largest value of the inner sum is $$\frac{2(19)-1}{19^2} = \frac{37}{361} > \frac{1}{10}$$ and this is the final term exceeding $1/10$.  This corresponds to $n = 19(19+1)/2 = 190$ (we did not add any additional $k$).

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the denominator, you need only do the following:

Figure out the denominator:
$$50 = \dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}$$

$$k^2-k-100=0$$

You get $k \approx 10.5$. So, the denominator of $a_{50}$ is 100. Now, we want the numerator. $$\dfrac{10(10-1)}{2} = 45$$ so the 45th term is the last time you do not get a denominator of less than 100.

This means $a_{50} = \dfrac{2*(50-45)-1}{100} = \dfrac{9}{100}$.

Now, for the sum, you have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{50} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{45} a_n + \sum_{n=46}^{50} a_n = 1 + \left(\dfrac{1+3}{4}\right) + \left(\dfrac{1+3+5}{9}\right) + \cdots + \sum_{n=46}^{50} a_n$$

But we know that $k^2 = 1+3+5+\cdots + (2k-1)$. So, we wind up with:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{45} a_n = \underbrace{1+1+\cdots + 1}_{9\text{ times}} = 9$$

Then $$\sum_{n=1}^{50} a_n = 9+\dfrac{1+3+5+7+9}{100} = 9.25$$

Finally, to calculate the largest $n$ such that $a_n\ge \dfrac{1}{10}$, you need:

$$\dfrac{2k-1}{k^2} \ge \dfrac{1}{10}$$

Try for equality and go a little smaller.

$$k^2-20k+10=0$$

$$k \approx 19.5$$

So, we want:
$$n\le \dfrac{19(20)}{2} = 190$$

Checking this out, we have:

$$n=190, a_{190} = \dfrac{37}{19^2} \approx 0.102$$

Comment: You're answers are wrong according to the markscheme

Comment: @JMoravitz my answer key comes from the Japanese Ministry of Education

Comment: @BrianBlumberg I was in the process of editing the answer. I was a bit off in the subscripts.

Comment: Yeah, now it's correct

Comment: Performing the calculations myself as well, Brian is correct.  (Sorry for jumping to conclusions without checking more thoroughly).  For the last part, we are wanting the final term for which the denominator is $19^2$.  The index of the last term (if we start with the index of $1$ as seems to be the case) which has denominator $k^2$ would occur at position $1+2+\dots+k$ which for $19$ would be $\frac{19\times 20}{2}=190$.  It seems you took the larger of the numbers rather than the smaller in the range.  Position $210$ would correspond to the term $\frac{39}{20^2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I was still correcting :)

Comment: That's one of the great things about giving hints instead of full answers.  I can leave the arithmetic mistakes for the reader to do rather than make them myself.  /cough

Comment: Very good point :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

For the second part, notice that $1 = \frac{1}{1}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{3}{9}+\frac{5}{9}$.  Make a prediction and attempt to prove it or find justification.

> $1+3+5+\dots+(2k-1) = k^2$ [Direct Proof that $1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots+ (2n - 1) = n\cdot n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136237/direct-proof-that-1-3-5-cdots-2n-1-n-cdot-n)

For the third part, it is clear that the largest such $n$ would occur at the end of one of the "groups" of terms who share the same denominator.  If it were the $k$'th such group, the last term would be of the form $\dfrac{2k-1}{k^2}$ and we ask what the largest $k$ would be still satisfying $\dfrac{2k-1}{k^2}\geq \dfrac{1}{10}$

> Rearranging, we are asking what the largest $k$ is such that $20k-10\geq k^2$.

Once done, reinterpret the results in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The terms with the same denominator $k^2$ come in groups of length $k$. Furthermore, the sum of the members of a group is always $1$.

Hence, the starting index of a group is a triangular number, $\dfrac{(k-1)k}2+1$ (for $1$-based indexing). The group containing $\color{green}{a_{50}}$ is with $k=10$, starting with $a_{46}$, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{100},\frac{3}{100},\frac{5}{100},\frac{7}{100},\color{green}{\frac{9}{100}},\cdots$$

---

The sum up to this terms is $9$ for the $9$ first complete groups, plus $\dfrac{25}{100}$ for the partial $10^{th}$ group, hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{50}t_n=\color{green}{\frac{37}4}.$$

---

The last (largest) element of a group is

$$\frac{2k-1}{k^2}$$ and this exceeds $\dfrac1{10}$ until $k=19$. Hence, the last element of this group is

$$\color{green}{a_{190}}.$$

Comment: The last answer is wrong. We had a discussion earlier. It should be the 190th term

Comment: How do you find the equation ((k-1)k)/2+1?

Comment: @BrianBlumberg: this is a triangular number. It yields the starting indexes $1,2,4,7,\cdots$ as should.

Comment: @BrianBlumberg: I spotted my mistake, fixing.