# Using induction to prove $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} i\cdot 2^i = (n - 1) \cdot 2^{n + 1} + 2$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have to prove the following proposition:

> $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} i\cdot 2^i = (n - 1) \cdot 2^{n + 1} + 2$$

I have the following proof thus far:

***Proof by Induction***

**Basis Step $(n = 1)$**

LHS: $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} i2^i = 1 \cdot 2^1 = 2$

RHS: $2^2(0) + 2 = 2$

LHS = RHS

**Inductive Hypothesis**

Assume that the proposition is true for $i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, k$

**Inductive Step $(n = k + 1)$**

LHS: $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} i2^i + (k + 1) \cdot 2^{k + 1} = 1 \cdot 2^1 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + \ldots + k \cdot 2^k + (k + 1) \cdot 2^{k + 1}$

RHS: $(k - 1) \cdot 2^{k + 1} + 2 + (k + 1) \cdot 2^{k + 1}\\ = (k - 1) \cdot 2^{k + 1} + (k + 1) \cdot 2^{k + 1} + 2\\ = ((k - 1) + (k + 1)) \cdot 2^{k + 1} + 2\\ = (2k) \cdot 2^{k + 1} + 2$

LHS = RHS

QED

Am I correct? If not, am I headed in the right direction? I understand the basics of induction, but am continuing to apply it. Thank you!

Comment: It's clearer and simpler to present the induction in [telescopic form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2938819/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you. I will take a look at that. Does what I have now look alright, though?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. In particular you should state explicitly where you invoked the induction hypothesis.If you follow the link you will see that the inductive step amounts to adding $(k+1)2^{k+1}$ to both sides of the hypothesized equality for $n=k.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base case is correct, but you need more information in the inductive hypothesis.

Base Case: $(n = 1)$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{1}i2^i = 1\cdot 2^1 = 2 = (1-1) \cdot 2^{1+1} + 2 $$
Inductive Hypothesis:
Assume that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} i2^i = (k-1) \cdot 2^{k+1} + 2 \hspace{1in} \text{IH}$$ for some integer $k >1$. You must show that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i2^i = k2^{k+2} + 2$$
Inductive Step:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i2^i = \sum_{i=1}^{k} i2^i+ \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+1} i2^i = (k-1) \cdot 2^{k+1} + 2 + (k+1)\cdot 2^{k+1} \hspace{.5in} \text{By IH}$$
$$= (k-1)\cdot 2^{k+1} + 2$$
$$= 2^{k+1} [ (k-1) + (k+1)] + 2$$
$$= 2^{k+1}\cdot 2k + 2$$
$$= k2^{k+1}\cdot 2^1 + 2$$
$$= k2^{k+2} + 2$$
Thus, 
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i2^i = (n-1) \cdot 2^{n+1} + 2 \ \text{for any } n\geq 1$

QED

Comment: The expression in the second line of the inductive step is not equal to the others.