# Sum of series proof $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i2^i$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How can I find the sum of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i2^i$ in a closed form. I have a feeling I can do this using differentiation of an existing series but cant seem to find it.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{i=1}^n i2^i = 2\sum_{i=1}^n i2^{i-1}$.

Comment: See the first answer (and others) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87030/proving-sum-limits-i-0n-i-2i-1-n1-2n-1-by-induction and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945281/solving-this-summation-sum-i-1k-i-cdot2i

Answer (score 3):

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k x^n = \frac{x^{k+1} - x }{x-1} $$

$$ \Rightarrow f'(x) = ??? \Rightarrow 2f'(2) = ??? $$

:-) not a complete answer to leave a chance for you to continue

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without calculus. It is an arithmetico-geometric progression, i.e. a series in which each term is a product of a term in an arithmetic progression and the corresponding term in a geometric progression. The technique is same as that used to evaluate a geometric progression.
Let $S = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i2^i$. 
The "geometric component" of the series is $2,2^2,2^3,\cdots$ so the common ratio is 2. Therefore $$
\begin{align}
2S &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}i2^{i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i+1-1)2^{i+1}\\
&= \sum_{i=2}^{n+1}i2^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i+1}\\
&= S+ (n+1)2^{n+1}-(1)2^1 -\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i+1}
\end{align}$$
Therefore $$S=(n+1)2^{n+1}-(1)2^1 -\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i+1}$$ which you can evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to another answer, if you let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i 2^i$, then $S_{n+1} = 2S_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^i = 2S_n + (2^{n+1} - 1)$. You can evaluate the first few terms with symbolic expressions and series and then prove a formula by induction using the recursion relation.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}p^{i} &= {p^{n + 1} - p \over p - 1}
\\[3mm]
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}ip^{i - 1}
&=
{\left(n + 1\right)p^{n} - 1 \over p - 1}
-
{p^{n + 1} - p \over \left(p - 1\right)^{2}}
\\[3mm]
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}ip^{i}
&=
{\left(n + 1\right)p^{n + 1} - p \over p - 1}
-
{p^{n + 2} - p^{2} \over \left(p - 1\right)^{2}}
\\[3mm]
\mbox{Set}\ p = 2\,;\quad
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i\,2^{i}
&=
\left\lbrack\left(n + 1\right)2^{n + 1} - 2\right\rbrack
-
\left\lbrack2^{n + 2} - 4\right\rbrack
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i\,2^{i}
=
\left(n - 1\right)2^{n + 1} + 2\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$