# Solving this summation: $\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot2^i$

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot2^i$$

I'm working on a recurrence relation question and now I'm stuck at this point. I have no idea how to simplify this down to something I can work with.  Can I seperate the terms into
$$\sum_{i=1}^k i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^k 2^i$$ and then just use the geometric series?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn

Comment: @labbhattacharjee This question asks for the sum of a finite series. The linked question asks for the sum of an infinite series. Does one of the 13 answers sum the finite series?

Comment: @bof, Observe the one by Eric Naslund

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Read the accepted answer to [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10087/what-is-the-definition-of-duplicate-question).

Comment: See also: [Proving $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n  i 2^{i-1} = (n+1) 2^n - 1$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87030)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the series
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} t^{k} = \frac{1-t^{n+1}}{1-t}.
\end{align}
Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} k t^{k-1} &= \frac{1}{(1-t)^{2}} \left( -(n+1) (1-t) t^{n}+(1-t^{n+1}) \right) \\
&= \frac{1 -(n+1) t^{n} + n t^{n+1}}{(1-t)^{2}}.
\end{align}
Now let $t=2$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \cdot 2^{k} = 2 -(n+1) 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+2} n = 2 + 2^{n+1}(n-1).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

No, you **can't** rewrite
$$\sum_{i=1}^ki\cdot2^i$$
as
$$\sum_{i=1}^ki\cdot\sum_{i=1}^k2^i.$$

In less time that it took to post the question, you could have checked the case $k=2$ on a calculator: is
$$1\cdot2+2\cdot4=(1+2)(2+4)?$$

However, you **can** write
$$\sum_{i=1}^ki\cdot2^i=\sum_{i=1}^k2^i+\sum_{i=2}^k2^i+\sum_{i=3}^k2^i+\cdots+\sum_{i=k}^k2^i.$$
Right? Now can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$=$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot2^i$
Consider $2S$=$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot2^{i+1}$.
Do $S-2S$ and the result is an G.P - an extra term $k2^{K+1}$.Find S.